# Android Automatically Selecting Tab when Scrolling Through Tabview

Tags: android, scroll, tabs, tabview

I'm working on an app where data is displayed in specific tabs by date (i.e. 31 different tabs). These are quite a lot of tabs and I want to make it more fluid for the user to scroll through the tabs. So, my goal is to automatically select the center tab, so that you can simply scroll through the tabs without having to click on them again.

My question: Is this possible? I first saw this concept in the trends overview of the "Samsung Health" app. How was that handled there?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials online regarding this. You might consider searching for `ViewPager` with `TabLayout`. Also, you can start from here - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I did not find this - this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great to know that helped.